# Can i generate a maven plugin descriptor (plugin.xml) with gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have the task of migrating a maven project, which has a java based maven plugin, to gradle. The plugin uses the maven-plugin-plugin and has the goals descriptor and helpmojo.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>help-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Is there any way i can execute these goals in gradle, or do i need to rewrite my java based maven plugin in gradle?

Comment: There's no build in support for that in Gradle and I'm not aware of any thirdparty plugin doing this.

Comment: No sure why you would use Gradle to build a Maven plugin project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this file with gradle by running this task code on build.gradle. This code generates a pom.xml temporary, runs maven with the temporary pom and generates plguin.xml file. Finally (on doLast) the task copies the file to the META-INF/maven/ directory.

```
task pluginDescriptor(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'mvn', '-e', '-B', 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor'
  doFirst {
    final File pom = project.file('pom.xml')
    install.repositories.mavenInstaller.pom.writeTo(pom)
    assert pom.file, "[$pom.canonicalPath] was not created"

    pom.text = pom.text.
            replace('<groupId>unknown</groupId>', "<groupId>${project.group}</groupId>").
            replace('<artifactId>empty-project</artifactId>', "<artifactId>${project.name}</artifactId>").
            replace('<version>0</version>', """
                                                          |<version>${version}</version>
                                                          |  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
                                                          |  <build>
                                                          |    <directory>\${project.basedir}/build</directory>
                                                          |    <outputDirectory>\${project.build.directory}/classes/main</outputDirectory>
                                                          |  </build>
                                                          |""".stripMargin().trim())
  }
  doLast {
    final pluginDescriptor = new File((File) project.compileGroovy.destinationDir, 'META-INF/maven/plugin.xml')
    assert pluginDescriptor.file, "[$pluginDescriptor.canonicalPath] was not created"
    println "Plugin descriptor file:$pluginDescriptor.canonicalPath is created successfully"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey. I tried your answer and it gives me an "Index out of bounds" error. Thanks for the help, but i think I am going to rewrite the maven plugin in gradle